# Laravel 5.5.x composer install in new environment fail to load php artisan file

Tags: composer-php, installation, laravel-5.5, php-7

Fail to do composer install in a new environment ...

Generating optimized autoload files

- php artisan package:discover
- In Finder.php line 547:  The "" directory does not exist.
- Script php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event 
  returned with error code 1

Composer.json file ...

---

```
"scripts": 
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "php artisan package:discover"
    ]
```

Full Output of Composer.json

```
{
"name": "WEB",
"description": "MY WEB.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1",
    "cornford/googlmapper": "2.*",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
    "netshell/paypal": "dev-master",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables": "^1.0",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~8.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
    "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helper/Utilities.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
        ]
    }
},

// With original script .. working fine in my dev vm, but other env its failing 
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
```

}

### On Ub 16.04

I Tried Everything from config-clean .. removing vendor folder and
other available suggestions as well. 
    Composer Install
    .
    .
    Composer dump-autoload

Comment: What **exactly** do you execute? And please share the complete `composer.json`

Comment: Please see the updated post -- @Nico Haase